# Java multiple processes running in parallel causing open file pointer exceptions

Tags: java, exception, parallel-processing

I have two Java programs that are scheduled to run one after the other. When they run in sequence without an overlap, there are no issues. But sometimes one of them gets prolonged a little while more due to the volume it is processing and the second one starts before the first one ends. Now, when this happens at a point when the second one is half way through completion it crashes giving the Max no of files open exception. The first one finishes successfully though. When run separately, with the same volume, there are no issues with either of them. Both processes are completely independent of each other - no common resources, invoked from different scripts and are finally 2 different processes running on the same OS on 2 different JVM's - I use a HP-UNIX system and have tried to trace the open handles using the TUSC utility but there aren't any that could cause such a problem. Xmx is 2Gigs for both and I doubt that would be reached - but is there an explanation to this that I am not seeing? Can the parallel runs be an issue or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: Can you provide a little detail on what it is the two programs are doing?  Are they opening sockets to external resources?  Are they reading internal files?  Sounds like you might be hitting an open file handle limit but I want to understand how you are making that happen.

Comment: Unless this is a strange bug resulting in a false report, you are definitely depleting the system-wide file handle limit. Just note that these handles are for every file-like resource, not just regular files. For example, network connections.

Comment: Sorry for not adding that in - Both the processes use Apache's FOP. They essentially create PDF files (process 1 around 300 pdfs but process2 creates around 20-30K PDF's) and that's just about what they do. Each of the two use a lot of resource files like fonts, images, etc but every one of them is being closed as per the tusc logs. I don't think they need to open anything external. But internal, yes. I don't know how reliable the TUSC utility is but would like to know the possible reasons behind this. When run separately process 2 can generate even 30-35k PDF's at a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem could be either to up your file descriptor limit (see link below) or to make sure that your code is properly closing resources (file input streams, sockets) so you are not leaking open file descriptors. I'll leave it up to you which approach you take.

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02261152/c02261152.pdf

**Edit**

If your program really is generating that many files at a time, I would certainly look into upping the open file descriptor limit.  Then, you might also consider putting in a throttle/regulator into the code.  Create X number of files and then back off for a few seconds, let the system reap the resources back and then continue on again.  This might be helpful.

Also, this link sounds very similar to your issue:

[Apache FOP 1.0 Multithreading - Too many open files err24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374729/apache-fop-1-0-multithreading-too-many-open-files-err24)

Comment: See SO link from above answer.  Might be the same issue you are seeing.  Process 2 might bring you so close to the resource limit that you have no additional overhead.  If process 1 then starts up, you crash into the limit.

Comment: Thanks for that - Its the same issue actually speaking - but that is based more on blaming FOP for the open file handles - I do not seem to think so. I smell a glitch either in the code or the maxfiles limit being touched due to some tunable on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar scenario and with resource constraints, we have used the below architecture.

There will be a monitor thread which will be started first which will have a count variable. There will be a configurable limit till which new processes will be created. For every new process, the count variable will be incremented. Once the process is completed, the count variable will be decremented. New processes will be created only if the count is lesser than the configured limit.

Above approach helped us to gain better control and able to scale up wherever it was possible.